# Layered pyramid in CSS without clip-path

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a result page with a pyramid. This pyramid consists of multiple layers (picture below). I created it with this property:

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
```

And it looks like this:

[Actual pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mMnM.png)

Users can export the result page to a PDF. The problem I'm facing is that it seems like clip-path isn't supported. The result on the pdf is this:

[Pyramid on pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUya0.png)

This means I have to create the same pyramid without clip-path, but I don't really know how to do it. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're saying "creating a result page", I assume that the horizontal lines in the pyramid can "fill" up with red, depending on the result.

I would recommend using an inline SVG, and then just color each row with a different in style attribute.

However, I needed to practice on linear-gradient, so I'm giving you that answer instead. You can assign different values to each row, as you go.

The first two rows are just covering up the rows diagonally to create the pyramid shape.

Change `--pyramid-size` if you want to scale the pyramid.

```css
.pyramid {
  --pyramid-size: 160px;

  --first-color:  #f95656;
  --second-color: #e2e5e5;
  --third-color:  #e2e5e5;
  --fourth-color: #e2e5e5;
  --fifth-color:  #e2e5e5;
  
  --cover-size: 66%;
  
  width: var(--pyramid-size);
  height: calc(var(--pyramid-size) * 130 / 160);

  background: 
    linear-gradient(58deg,  transparent var(--cover-size), white var(--cover-size)),
    linear-gradient(-58deg, transparent var(--cover-size), white var(--cover-size)),

    linear-gradient(180deg,  var(--first-color)  19%,
    rgb(255,255,255)    19%, rgb(255,255,255)    21%,
    var(--second-color) 21%, var(--second-color) 39%,
    rgb(255,255,255)    39%, rgba(255,255,255)   41%,
    var(--third-color)  41%, var(--third-color)  59%,
    rgb(255,255,255)    59%, rgba(255,255,255)   61%,
    var(--fourth-color) 61%, var(--fourth-color) 79%,
    rgb(255,255,255)    79%, rgb(255,255,255)    81%,
    var(--fifth-color)  81%);
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid"></div>
```